# Get list of files which are not in sync between local and remote repository using Egit

Tags: git, github, egit

Currently I am using EGit(integrated with eclipse) to pull and push changes to GitHub.

I want to know is there way using EGit I can get all files which are not in sync between local and remote repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ["Comparing with Branches (Synchronize)" feature](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Comparing_with_Branches_.28Synchronize.29):

The>  difference between the working tree (including not committed changes) and a branch or tag can be viewed (since EGit 3.1) by selecting the project(s) you want to compare and clicking `Compare With > Branch, Tag or Reference`. The result is filtered for the resources you selected before starting the comparison.

> You can also compare with a branch by clicking the dynamic menu `Team > Synchronize` on a project and selecting the Ref you want to synchronize your working tree against.
>   If the Git repository contains multiple Eclipse projects it is sufficient to select one project, the Synchronization View will also include all other projects.

[image: http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/9/9b/Egit-1.0-synchronize-dynamic.png]